# Use derived class property in base class constructor

Tags: c#

In following code, I need `Base` class constructor to use `Derived` class property `ServiceUrl`. I cannot define `ServiceUrl` as static as it's value is computed based on `Derived` class constructor argument. I cannot pass `ServiceUrl` as constructor argument to `Base` class since the computation is not as trivial as illustrated and it may require access other fields in `Base`/`Derived` classes.

Any suggestions for the best way out? I have permissions to make any change to `Base` and `Derived` class structures to attain the purpose.

```
abstract class Base 
{
    public abstract string ServiceUrl { get; }

    public Base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ServiceUrl);
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override string ServiceUrl { get; private set; }

    public Derived(string rootUrl) : base()
    {
        ServiceUrl = rootUrl + "/service";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be on the constructor? because you first call the base constructor and only then you can start the stuff in your constructor...

Comment: Yeah.. I too think passing to constructor is a common sense for this situation. I can probably call base class constructor as `base(GetServiceUrl())` which internally sets `ServiceUrl` and returns its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class constructor will always be called before the derived class constructor. Therefore, there are exactly two solutions:

1. Use a parameter in the constructor of your base class:

   ```
   abstract class Base 
   {
       public string ServiceUrl { get; }

       public Base(string serviceUrl)
       {
           ServiceUrl = serviceUrl;

           Console.WriteLine(ServiceUrl);
       }
   }

   class Derived : Base
   {
       public Derived(string rootUrl) : base(rootUrl + "/service")
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Don't use the variable in the constructor. Use it at a later point.

Comment: Nice idea.. I should make `ServiceUrl` as non-`abstract` property in base class.